# Eclipse resource editor for Win32

Tags: windows, eclipse, resources, rc

MS Visual Studio includes the resource editor to create icons, cursors, windows, etc. Is there anything similar for Eclipse?

How do developers create Windows with Eclipse? They can be done programmatically, but that's not very convenient, trying to figure out all the coordinates, position of buttons, etc. Designing in a editor is much simpler.

I am creating a Win32 app, Qt and other frameworks are not useful for this purpose.

Are the only choices to either do it outside of Eclipse with some 3rd party tool or to do it programmatically?

Comment: Have you looked into this?
http://www.eclipse.org/vep/

I haven't tried it, so I don't know the extent of language support.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be a framework for creating GUI builders, not an actual resource editor, if I understood correctly. Or did I get it wrong?